# Do walnut trees grow in rain forests?

Tags: optimal-conditions, walnut, nut-trees, climate

A few things that I'm interested to know about:

- What's the required temperature for growing walnut trees ([Juglans regia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juglans_regia))?
- Do they grow in hill areas?
- How long does it take to produce fruit from the day it was planted as a young tree?

Comment: Hi, Prashanth! By walnut do you mean Juglans regia or Juglans nigra?

Comment: @Alina It's Juglans regia; would be great if I get details on both :)

Comment: In our very humid tropical montane forest in Colombia we grow Juglans Neotropica

Comment: Juglans nigra is native to North America, while Juglans regia is from Eurasia, however they are similar. There are other Juglanses that might be quite different than the two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minimum temperature changes among walnut (Juglans regia) varieties (where I live, the walnuts withstand -30 to -40°C / or -22 to -40°F). The maximum temperature is generally around 35°C (95°F) and above this the twigs, leaves and fruits start to burn. Walnuts survive even if the temperature goes occasionally in some days to 45°C (113°F), although I don't know for how long.

They grow on plain and hill areas and they require a lot of sunlight, so if you plant them on a slope, choose the sunniest side, usually facing south, SE or SW. If the temperature rises above 35°C (95°F) on a regular basis, then plant the walnuts on the NE or NW side of the hill.

If they are planted from seed, they will fruit after 7-10 years. If they are planted from commercial varieties (usually grafted, but not always), they can start bearing fruits 5-7 years after purchasing, assuming they are at least 2 years old. In any case, a consistent harvest will come after 10 years.

There are also a few things that need to be taken in consideration. First, walnuts don't like overwatering, and second they don't like growing in shaded areas. So, if you plant a walnut tree in a rainforest, it might survive, but it won't thrive. To improve their chances, plant them at a safe distance so other trees don't cast shadows on them, and make sure the water is draining really well.